# Using JS, jQuery, ajax, & json, I need help optimizing page load speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am building a user profile page, using jQuery, pulling from a json type database. I am fairly inexperienced at using ajax to populate the page, so right now, the page load takes far too long. If I could get some help refining my code, to optimize and speed up the page load, I would really appreciate it.

Goal: I am trying to take info from a JSON database that is built for a number of users with multiple data points to capture. Here is an example of the JSON data. I would like to have the information displayed once it's tab has been selected.
There is a large amount of data within each profile, specifically the publications. A user can have any amount of pubs, and my code now loops through all of the data before writing it to the page.

```js
{
  "Error": false,
  "Cached": false,
  "Profile": {
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Smith",
    "PreferredName": "",
    "Email": "JohnSmith@example.com",
    "Gender": "",
    "PhoneNumber": "1234567890",
    "Office": "Todd Hall Addition 570B",
    "EndowedPosition": "MAJOR POSITION #1",
    "Biography": "THIS IS A BIOGRAPHY",
    "Appointments": [
      {
        "Title": "Title 1",
        "WorkingTitle": "",
        "Rank": "",
        "Department": "Department1",
        "Start": "2014-01-01",
        "End": ""
      },
      {
        "Title": "",
        "WorkingTitle": "",
        "Rank": "Rank 1",
        "Department": "Department2",
        "Start": "2014-01-01",
        "End": ""
      },
      {
        "Title": "Title 2",
        "WorkingTitle": "",
        "Rank": "",
        "Department": "",
        "Start": "2014-01-01",
        "End": ""
      }
    ],
    "IntellectualContributions": [
      {
        "Type": "Book",
        "TypeOther": "",
        "IncludeProfile": "Yes",
        "Status": "Published",
        "Title": "TitleMain",
        "TitleSecondary": "",
        "FirstName": null,
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "Role": null,
        "JournalName": "",
        "Publisher": "",
        "Volume": "",
        "IssueNum": "",
        "PageNum": "",
        "WebAddress": "",
        "CaseNum": "",
        "YearPub": "",
        "Authors": []
      },
      {
        "Type": "Journal Article",
        "TypeOther": "",
        "IncludeProfile": "Yes",
        "Status": "Published",
        "Title": "TitleMain",
        "TitleSecondary": "",
        "FirstName": null,
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "Role": null,
        "JournalName": "",
        "Publisher": "",
        "Volume": "",
        "IssueNum": "",
        "PageNum": "",
        "WebAddress": "",
        "CaseNum": "",
        "YearPub": "",
        "Authors": []
      },
      {
        "Type": "Manuscript",
        "TypeOther": "",
        "IncludeProfile": "Yes",
        "Status": "Published",
        "Title": "TITLEMAIN",
        "TitleSecondary": "",
        "FirstName": null,
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "Role": null,
        "JournalName": "",
        "Publisher": "",
        "Volume": "",
        "IssueNum": "",
        "PageNum": "",
        "WebAddress": "",
        "CaseNum": "",
        "YearPub": "",
        "Authors": []
      },
      {
        "Type": "Book Review",
        "TypeOther": "",
        "IncludeProfile": "Yes",
        "Status": "Published",
        "Title": "Title",
        "TitleSecondary": "",
        "FirstName": null,
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "Role": null,
        "JournalName": "",
        "Publisher": "",
        "Volume": "",
        "IssueNum": "",
        "PageNum": "",
        "WebAddress": "",
        "CaseNum": "",
        "YearPub": "",
        "Authors": ["Author1"]
      },
      {
        "Type": "Newspaper",
        "TypeOther": "",
        "IncludeProfile": "Yes",
        "Status": "Published",
        "Title": "Title",
        "TitleSecondary": "",
        "FirstName": null,
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "Role": null,
        "JournalName": "",
        "Publisher": "",
        "Volume": "",
        "IssueNum": "",
        "PageNum": "",
        "WebAddress": "",
        "CaseNum": "",
        "YearPub": "",
        "Authors": [
          "Author 1",
          "Author 2",
          "Author 3",
          "Author 4"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Type": "Journal Article",
        "TypeOther": "",
        "IncludeProfile": "Yes",
        "Status": "Published",
        "Title": "Title",
        "TitleSecondary": "",
        "FirstName": null,
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "Role": null,
        "JournalName": "",
        "Publisher": "",
        "Volume": "",
        "IssueNum": "",
        "PageNum": "",
        "WebAddress": "",
        "CaseNum": "",
        "YearPub": "",
        "Authors": []
      },
      {
        "Type": "Journal Article",
        "TypeOther": "",
        "IncludeProfile": "Yes",
        "Status": "Published",
        "Title": "TITLE",
        "TitleSecondary": "",
        "FirstName": null,
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "Role": null,
        "JournalName": "",
        "Publisher": "",
        "Volume": "",
        "IssueNum": "",
        "PageNum": "",
        "WebAddress": "",
        "CaseNum": "",
        "YearPub": "",
        "Authors": []
      },
      {
        "Type": "Journal Article",
        "TypeOther": "",
        "IncludeProfile": "Yes",
        "Status": "Published",
        "Title": "TITLE",
        "TitleSecondary": "",
        "FirstName": null,
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "Role": null,
        "JournalName": "",
        "Publisher": "",
        "Volume": "",
        "IssueNum": "",
        "PageNum": "",
        "WebAddress": "",
        "CaseNum": "",
        "YearPub": "",
        "Authors": ["Author 1"]
      },
      {
        "Type": "Journal Article",
        "TypeOther": "",
        "IncludeProfile": "Yes",
        "Status": "Submitted",
        "Title": "Title",
        "TitleSecondary": "",
        "FirstName": null,
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "Role": null,
        "JournalName": "",
        "Publisher": "",
        "Volume": "",
        "IssueNum": "",
        "PageNum": "",
        "WebAddress": "",
        "CaseNum": "",
        "YearPub": "",
        "Authors": []
      },
      {
        "Type": "Journal Article",
        "TypeOther": "",
        "IncludeProfile": "Yes",
        "Status": "Working Paper",
        "Title": "TITLE",
        "TitleSecondary": "",
        "FirstName": null,
        "MiddleName": null,
        "LastName": null,
        "Role": null,
        "JournalName": "",
        "Publisher": "",
        "Volume": "",
        "IssueNum": "",
        "PageNum": "",
        "WebAddress": "",
        "CaseNum": "",
        "YearPub": "",
        "Authors": []
      }
    ],
    "Education": [
      {
        "DegreeType": "PhD",
        "DegreeOther": "",
        "School": "University",
        "Major": "MAJOR 1",
        "FocusArea": "Focus Area",
        "DissertationTitle": "Dissertation Title",
        "Highest": "Yes"
      },
      {
        "DegreeType": "MBA",
        "DegreeOther": "",
        "School": "University",
        "Major": "MAJOR 1",
        "FocusArea": "",
        "DissertationTitle": "",
        "Highest": ""
      },
      {
        "DegreeType": "BBA",
        "DegreeOther": "",
        "School": "University",
        "Major": "MAJOR 1",
        "FocusArea": "",
        "DissertationTitle": "",
        "Highest": ""
      }
    ],
    "Present": [
      {
        "Title": "Presentation Title",
        "Type": "Oral Presentation",
        "Name": "NAME",
        "Authors": [
          "Author1",
          "Author2",
          "Author3",
          "Author4"
        ],
        "Date": "2014"
      },
      {
        "Title": "Presentation Title",
        "Type": "Oral Presentation",
        "Name": "NAME",
        "Authors": [
          "Author1",
          "Author2",
          "Author3"
        ],
        "Date": "2014"
      },
      {
        "Title": "PRESENTATION TITLE",
        "Type": "Oral Presentation",
        "Name": "NAME",
        "Authors": [
          "Author1",
          "Author2",
          "Author3",
          "Author4",
          "Author5"
        ],
        "Date": "2013"
      },
      {
        "Title": "PRESENTATION TITLE",
        "Type": "Oral Presentation",
        "Name": "NAME",
        "Authors": [
          "Author1",
          "Author2",
          "Author3",
          "Author4",
          "Author5"
        ],
        "Date": "2013"
      },
      {
        "Title": "PRESENTATION TITLE",
        "Type": "Paper",
        "Name": "NAME",
        "Authors": [
          "Author1",
          "Author2",
          "Author3",
          "Author4",
          "Author5"
        ],
        "Date": "2012"
      },
      {
        "Title": "PRESENTATION TITLE",
        "Type": "Oral Presentation",
        "Name": "NAME",
        "Authors": [
          "Author1",
          "Author2",
          "Author3",
          "Author4",
          "Author5"
        ],
        "Date": "2012"
      },
      {
        "Title": "PRESENTATION TITLE",
        "Type": "Oral Presentation",
        "Name": "NAME",
        "Authors": [
          "Author1",
          "Author2",
          "Author3"
        ],
        "Date": "2012"
      },
      {
        "Title": "PRESENTATION TITLE",
        "Type": "Oral Presentation",
        "Name": "NAME",
        "Authors": [
          "Author1",
          "Author2"
        ],
        "Date": "2012"
      },
      {
        "Title": "PRESENTATION TITLE",
        "Type": "Oral Presentation",
        "Name": "NAME",
        "Authors": [
          "Author1",
          "Author2",
        ],
        "Date": "2012"
      },
      {
        "Title": "PRESENTATION TITLE",
        "Type": "Oral Presentation",
        "Name": "NAME",
        "Authors": [
          "Author1",
          "Author2",
          "Author3"
        ],
        "Date": "2012"
      }
    ],
    "Departments": [
      "Department1",
      "Department2"
    ],
    "Research": [
      "Research1",
      "Research2",
      "Research3",
      "Research4",
      "Research5"
    ],
    "Teaching": [
      "Teaching1",
      "Teaching2",
      "Teaching3",
      "Teaching4"
    ]
  }
}
```

[Here is a link to my HTML/JS](https://jsfiddle.net/6chkyebc/)

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In developer console look at the Network tab and see which calls are taking the longest. You can also try to profile your code. Also the function in the jsfiddle I saw how you broke it down into  /*education*/ /*bio*/ /*etc*/ sections but these should be helper functions to make it more readable. Your js looks fine, its probably server related.

Comment: It also helps to know what technologies you are using.  E.g., it sounds like the tags are potential new tech for your site, but what is the current setup?  An approach to cleaning up ASP.NET web forms will be drastically different from MVC, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is too wide, and it doesn't fit well [as an stackoverflow ideal question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). So take this answer as a sort of long comment with formatting: I can't solve your issue and I'm afraid no one can with the information provided.

How many time means 'too long' in your question?

When you say that 'page load' takes too long, you actually mean **page load**, or **user information load**? Those are different things. **I bet you're referring to the time needed to load a user information**, and I'll try to answer so. A whole page loading being slow is an issue that should have nothing to do with bringing data from AJAX -in fact, get some data in a separate request alleviates the initial document load-.

How many time do your **database query** consume? How many time does the **network request** take? -you can use the *network tab* in the [chrome developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) to check that-. I'm pretty sure either the database query or the networking are the main cause of the bottleneck. While your jQuery code looping through the data is heavy and long, usually networking/database are better candidates for performance bottlenecks than runtime execution.

If your db query takes too long, you should check it and maybe post a sql related question. Maybe you're just grabbing to much info at once, maybe you're firing too many consecutive unneeded queries against your db... it's just not jQuery matter.

If the query consumes little time, but the server still takes too long to give the response, also there is nothing we can tell you here: it's a problem related with your platform and web server.

If both the query and the network work fine, but still the javascript code in the client is taking too much time to render the data -I don't believe that can be the case... but well, who knows-, then you should try to reproduce the issue **with no http/db request interaction**:

You should isolate your code that parses the response and render it to the DOM to a function, and call it with a fake response, and see how many time it needs to do its work. In such a situation you can fire a stackoverflow question which is easily reproducible, so folks here can help you easier :-)

I tried to set up such, in fact, but I found an `unexpected token else` here:

```
else{
    //continue original If Statements to check PublishedType
}
```

If your code is behaving **slow**, then sure it's different from the one you pasted here, since it's giving a syntax error. If your problem is just that syntax error, then it has nothing to do with performance.

Btw, sure your code would benefit from a refactor ;-)